# Get all values for a certain property name in linq?

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a way to get all values for a certain key in linq?

Here is my collection

> [PId, Pname, EnviornementName]

So I have a collection of this type,  Looking for a more generic approach, where i could check the property name and do a select. Something like,

> myCollection.SelectMany(item => item).Where(item==propertyName)

how can i do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get an array of `named` property values try

```
var pName = "PId";
var values = myCollection
  .Select(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(pName).GetValue(x, null))
  .ToArray();
```

Comment: I get a NullReferenceException when i call Count() even though the query was supposed to return 3 items

Comment: What? `values` is an `Array` use `Length`.  However you should get a compiler error not run-time Exception.

Comment: Yeah, i figured out the problem, I didn't make PId a property, hence it caused the exception.

Comment: @RichardSchneider - Worked like a charm! thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Linq;

MyCollection.Select(x => x.Pid).ToArray();
```

Or to get unique values

```
MyCollection.Select(x => x.Pid).Distinct().ToArray();
```

Or better yet, a sorted array of unique values

```
MyCollection
  .OrderBy(x => x.Pid)
  .Select(x = x.Pid)
  .Distinct()
  .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, please look for the update on the question,

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it, for example:

```
var IDs = from o in myCollection
          select new { o.PId };
```

or

```
var IDs = myCollection.Select(o => o.PId);
```

I suggest that you start with some linq tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/linq/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Looking for a more generic approach, where i could check the property name and do a select. Something like, myCollection.SelectMany(item => item).Where(item==propertyName) how can i do this?

Comment: It sounds like you want to pass a column name as parameter to linq. In such case, there is already an answered question posted. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963242/how-to-write-linq-query-with-column-name-as-parameter-still-in-a-type-safe-way

Comment: Thanks. will look in to it.